# How to embed .manifest file using Reflection.Emit?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I want to embed a .manifest file inside my generated assembly (I am using .NET Framework 4.8.1).

There is a method called `DefineManifestResource` on `ModuleBuilder`, but I'm not sure if it is the right thing as it requires a name for the resource, and the documentation is quite lackluster.